# How to test active resource like models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails, http-mock

I am using a gem called [spyke](https://github.com/balvig/spyke) for my rails models. Spyke is similar to active resource and uses JSON API as data source. I want to write tests using rspec and factory girl.

How can I set up a mock data source for testing? So far I have found httpmock which is part of active_resource, I am looking for something similar,  preferably an independent gem/library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout webmock, fakeweb, vcr, pact(your own api only)

Comment: Pact looks like a perfect fit. Thanks!